# C# Creation of DB on Firestore fails with no error message

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am following the docs on how to set up a backend with firestore:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0#c_1

I already set up a service account, genereted a key file and fed that into the code on my end. The connection works and I set the right permission (owner) to be able to read the bucket list.

But as soon as I try the first line of code from the tutorial:

```
FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create(project);
Console.WriteLine("Created Cloud Firestore client with project ID: {0}", project);
```

The execution dies. It doesnt lead to an error message, it doesnt run into a catch block with an exception. It just doesnt continue after the Create(project) part.

I noticed however, that the created datebase on the firebase console and the service account dont seem to be connected yet. Also, I dont know what to put for "project". I tried the project Id from the service account (with which i can do listbuckets) but this doesnt seem to work.

In the docs it does not state anything about what else to do.

Can you guys give me a hint maybe?

Thank you

EDIT:

LONGER CODE EXCEPT:

```
 var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("/Users/juliustolksdorf/Projects/Interior Circle/keys/interiorcircle-4f70f209e160.json");
                var storage = StorageClient.Create(credential);

                // Make an authenticated API request.
                var buckets = storage.ListBuckets("interiorcircle");
                foreach (var bucket in buckets)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(bucket.Name);
                }


                var db = FirestoreDb.Create("interiorcircle");
                DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("users").Document("alovelace");
                Dictionary<string, object> user = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                     { "First", "Ada" },
                     { "Last", "Lovelace" },
                     { "Born", 1815 }
                };
                await docRef.SetAsync(user);


            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                DisplayAlert("hi", e.ToString(), "ok");

            }
```

List buckets works, so the key is set correctly, but as soon as I try to do the create DB it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to the [Firestore .NET Client Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest).

In order to connect, you should pass the `projectId` to `FirestoreDb.Create` and you should set and environment variable called `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` which contains the path to your service account JSON file.

Edit:

You can also explicitly pass the credential to FirestoreDb, by using:

```cs
FirestoreDb db = new FirestoreDbBuilder { ProjectId = projectId, Credential = credential }.Build();
```

Comment: but i did both. see my updated code.

Comment: But did you set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` that I said? because you are not passing the credential to the FirestoreDb, so it makes sense not to work

Comment: I have also added an explicit way of setting the credential

Comment: Thank you very much! This infact worked! Setting the envoirment variable with my mac seems to have not worked. Another thing, you have an error in that line, it is "credentialsPath" not just crendtial! But this did work!!

Comment: It is not an error, you have the `Credential` object created in the first line, no need to create it twice, you can just pass the `Credential` object. But `CredentialPath` works fine aswell :) You can upvote the answer so more people get to see it.